# Apache - Redirecting requests to a different machineon a local network based on the hostname

Tags: linux, apache, apache2

I have two servers A (192.168.1.100) and B(192.168.1.101) on my local network and one external IP. I would like to forward the HTTP request based on the sub-domains. For instance i would like to have any http request to a.example.com would go to server A 192.168.1.100 and any request to b.example.com go to server B 192.168.1.101. Is there any options that I can implement on Server A Apache configuration files to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this could be better handled by a router or an iptables rule.

This said, you could setup a virtual host entry on machine A, forwarding all requests to your second machine B

```
<virtualHost *:80>
    ServerName b.example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* http://192.168.1.101$0 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

The `[P]` flag forwards the requests to `mod_proxy`, so this must be enabled. Another caveat is the performance warning at [RewriteRule Flags - P|proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p).

Last point, this is untested, so please be careful.